# Static Cast to CRTP Interface

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I am building up a CRTP interface and noticed some undefined behavior. So, I built up some sample code to narrow down the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    int a() const { return static_cast<T const&>(*this).a_IMPL(); }
    int b() const { return static_cast<T const&>(*this).b_IMPL(); }
    int c() const { return static_cast<T const&>(*this).c_IMPL(); }
};

class A : public Base<A> {
public:
    A(int a, int b, int c) : _a(a), _b(b), _c(c) {}

    int a_IMPL() const { return _a; }
    int b_IMPL() const { return _b; }
    int c_IMPL() const { return _c; }
    
private:
    int _a;
    int _b;
    int _c;
};

template <typename T>
void foo(const T& v) {
    std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "a() = " << static_cast<Base<T>>(v).a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b() = " << static_cast<Base<T>>(v).b() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c() = " << static_cast<Base<T>>(v).c() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A v(10, 20, 30);
    
    std::cout << "a() = " << v.a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b() = " << v.b() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c() = " << v.c() << std::endl;
    
    foo(v);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
a() = 10
b() = 20
c() = 30
foo()
a() = 134217855
b() = 0
c() = -917692416
```

It appears that there is some problem when casting the child class, which implements the CRTP "interface", to the interface itself. This doesn't make sense to me because the class A plainly inherits from Base so, shouldn't I be able to cast an instance of A into Base?

Thanks!

Comment: `static_cast<Base<T>>` - you are casting to a value, thus causing slicing.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica You're right. I made a silly mistake...

Answer (score 0):

You copy and slice when you cast to `Base<T>`.

Cast to a `const Base<T>&` instead:

```
std::cout << "a() = " << static_cast<const Base<T>&>(v).a() << std::endl;
std::cout << "b() = " << static_cast<const Base<T>&>(v).b() << std::endl;
std::cout << "c() = " << static_cast<const Base<T>&>(v).c() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was casting incorrectly to a value rather than a reference

```
std::cout << "a() = " << static_cast<Base<T>>(v).a() << std::endl;
```

should become

```
std::cout << "a() = " << static_cast<const Base<T>&>(v).a() << std::endl;
```

Comment: ... well, that's what my answer said already :-)